# Rotation method called in child view of UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, rotation

I have a view hierarchy embedded in a navigation controller. What methods get called in the child view controllers when the view rotates? This code is in one of the child views of the navigation controller and neither of these methods get called!

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    NSLog(@"1");
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        return true;
    }else{
        if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return false;

}

-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    [self loadCorrectElements];
    NSLog(@"2");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should get both of

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

So something else is wrong with your setup.

to be clear, as you mention "child views" - you mean the topmost UIViewController? That is the one that will intercept these messages during rotation.